# How to batch rename file/folder - insert a character after n character

Tags: macos, terminal, rename, batch-rename

Using mac terminal, how to batch rename filders/files - insert desired characters after desired character from beginning. With no symbol patterns - just offsetting inserts.

So I need to Insert `-` character after every 4 first characters in the name of folder/file.

From this:

```
"20190127 Blabla"
"20180914_Blah"
"20171214Blah"
"123456789"
```

into this:

```
"2019-0127 Blabla"
"2018-0914_Blah"
"2017-1214Blah"
"1234-56789"
```

and better straight away to this:

```
"2019-01-27 Blabla"
"2018-09-14_Blah"
"2017-12-14Blah"
"1234-56-789"
```

Generally speaking, I need to change date format from `YYYYMMDD` to `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Not a mac guy myself, but this seems relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284282/rename-files-add-dashes-after-fourth-and-sixth-characters

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'v been searching.